# Parameter Named("key") Key key not showing in api explorer after google endpoints migration to version 2

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I migrated Google endpoints version 1 project to google endpoints too. After the migration a parameter names exactly like this

```
@Named("key") Key key
```

Does not show up in the api explorer.

However when I change the key to a different name like 
@Named("serializeablekey") Key serializeablekey
Then I am able to see the parameter appear in api explorer.

The exact method is like this

```
public SimpleValue update(User user, @Named("key") Key key, SomeDTOClass dto, @Named("anotherkey") Key anotherkey) throws ServiceException
```

The Key is 
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key

The ApiMethod annotation is like this

```
@ApiMethod(httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.PUT, name="sample.update", path = "sample.update")
```

The closest problem I see are these warnings on the console when I run the application locally

```
Aug 20, 2018 7:50:58 PM com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JacksonResourceSchemaProvider hasUnresolvedType
WARNING: skipping field of type java.lang.Class<?> because it is unresolved
Aug 20, 2018 7:50:58 PM com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JacksonResourceSchemaProvider getResourceSchema
WARNING: skipping field 'class' of type 'java.lang.Class<?>' because it is unresolved.
Aug 20, 2018 7:50:58 PM com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JacksonResourceSchemaProvider hasUnresolvedType
WARNING: skipping field of type java.lang.Class<?> because it is unresolved
Aug 20, 2018 7:50:58 PM com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JacksonResourceSchemaProvider getResourceSchema
WARNING: skipping field 'class' of type 'java.lang.Class<?>' because it is unresolved.
```

Is there some known issued with the Named annotation?

Comment: I think this is because "key" is a standard parameter for an API key. Are you able to link to a version of your app running Endpoints v1?

Comment: @saiyr I have access to the app running endpoints v1 and the Named("key") there works just well, can be seen in api explorer. I can't put the url here because it is in production. Why would it work in Endpoints v1 but not v2 ?

Comment: It's likely a bug related to how API metadata is generated. I'll do some testing for the proper behavior.

Comment: Hello, after doing some manual testing, I have not been able to replicate this. Can you show a screenshot of this working? I think technically even though it's not in the standard field, you could get around this by clicking the gear and selecting the API key/client ID option.